# How can I get the coordinates of an element within a WrapPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can i get the cordinates of an element inside the WrapPanel?
I have already tried with myElementInsidenList.TransformToAncestor(rootView).Transform(new Point(0, 0)) but isn't working.

```
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="myScrollViewer" Background="#2B2B2B" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ScrollViewer.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                        <Border CornerRadius="12" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ScrollViewer.Template>
                <WrapPanel x:Name="nList" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </ScrollViewer>
```

[More context](https://github.com/Dreaming-Codes/DreamingSortingWPF/blob/3cb8ec9998bbcf658f6706ca1eb9224243aa159f/DreamingSortingWPF/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L94)

Comment: Why do you want the coordinates?

Comment: Please take your time to post the context as embedded code instead of attaching a resource link. The code should contain the minimal version of the related context to make understanding your problem easier. It's not clear what you are trying to do, so it's not possible to suggest an alternative solution to you. At first glance what you are doing appears to overcomplicated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Dai I need it to do an animation where I transpose one object over another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wait before the `Visual` element is rendered. Otherwise there is no position to retrieve.

Also note that your doAnimationAndAddValue() method must return a `Task` instead of `void`, if it is an `async` method that is not an event handler.

Simply listen to the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event:

```
async Task doAnimationAndAddValue()
{
  TextBox targetInput = CloneXaml(cloneInputForAnimation);
  nList.Children.Add(targetInput);
  targetInput.Loaded += OnTargetInputLoaded;
}

private void OnTargetInputLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var targetInput = sender as FrameworkElement;
  targetInput.Loaded -= OnTargetInputLoaded;

  Point targetPositionRelativeToWrapPanel = 
    targetInput.TransformToVisual(this.nList).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

  Point targetPositionRelativeToMainWindow = 
    targetInput.TransformToVisual(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
}
```